# $X,Y~$i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ $U=1+2(Y/X)$ Find the pdf of $U$

Tags: probability

$X,Y~$i.i.d. $N(0,1)$  $U=1+2(Y/X)$  I need help finding a $V(X,Y)$ that allows me to find the pdf of $U$.

Comment: What is a $V(X,Y)$?

Comment: another function so i can use the change of variables formula

Comment: Will you edit your question to include the steps you've taken so far and where you are stuck? Lead us to the point where you are trying to find $V(X,Y)$ so we can see what hints and directions to give! Thanks.

Comment: The notation and abbreviations you use might not be universally known. Can you please expand your post?

Answer (score 0):

Putting $Z=Y/X$, we have to find
$$
F_U(u)=\Bbb{P}\left(U \le u\right)=\Bbb{P}\left(1+2\frac{Y}{X} \le u\right)=\Bbb{P}\left(Z\le \frac{u-1}{2}\right)=F_Z\left(\frac{u-1}{2}\right)
$$
and differentiating 
$$
f_U(u)=\frac{1}{2}f_Z\left(\frac{u-1}{2}\right)
$$
Observe that when $X$ and $Y$ are two independent normally distributed random variables with expected value 0 and variance 1, then the ratio $Y/X$ has the standard Cauchy distribution, i.e. if $X, Y \sim \textrm{N}(0,1),\, X, Y$ independent, then $Z=\tfrac{Y}{X} \sim \textrm{Cauchy}(0,1)$ with pdf
$$
  f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\pi (1 + z^2)}.
$$
thus we find
$$
f_U(u)=\frac{1}{2}f_Z\left(\frac{u-1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{u-1}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{2}{4+\left(u-1\right)^2}
$$
that is $U\sim\textrm{Cauchy}(1,2)$.

Remind that $Z\sim\textrm{Cauchy}(\mu,\gamma)$ is a Cauchy distribution with location parameter $\mu$ (specifying the location of the peak of the distribution) and scale factor $\gamma$ (which specifies the half-width at half-maximum) and has the probability density function
$$
    f(x; \mu,\gamma) = \frac{1}{\pi\gamma \left[1 + \left(\frac{x - \mu}{\gamma}\right)^2\right]} =\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2+(x - \mu)^2 }.
$$